# Flask. Blueprint. Не применяются стили CSS к странице с формой при обращении с методом POST

Tags: css, flask, form, blueprint

Столкнулся с тем, что если при иcпользовании Blueprint страница с формой в blueprint использует стили CSS из папки static приложения, то при первом открытии формы стили подтягиваются, но если в обработчик url формы добавить метод POST и в шаблоне страницы назначить action = обработчик URL этой же формы, то после отправки данных формы стили уже не подтягиваются.

Структура приложения.

```
app-|
    |-static-|
    |        |-main.css
    |
    |-Templates-|
    |           |-base_adm.html
    |
    |-main-|
    |      |-Templates-|
    |      |           |-login_form.html
    |      |
    |      |-__init__.py
    |
    |-__init__.py
```

_

```
# /app/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
...
app = Flask(__name__)
...
from .main import main as main_blp
app.register_blueprint(main_blp, url_prefix='')
```

_

```
# /app/templates/base_adm.html

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ the_title }}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

_

```
# /app/main/__init__.py

from flask import Blueprint, render_template
    
main = Blueprint('main', __name__, template_folder='templates') 

@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template('login_form.html', message='Привет')
```

_

```
# /app/main/templates/login_form.html

{% extends 'base_adm.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<form method='POST' name="add" action={{ url_for(".login") }}>
    <div class="div_nav1">
        <input class='input_filtr' name='user' type='TEXT' value='' placeholder="Логин" size="3">
    </div>
    <div class="div_nav1">
        <input class='input_filtr' name='password' type='TEXT' value="" placeholder="Пароль" size="50">
    </div>
    <div class="div_float">
        <input class='form_button' name='button_add' value='Войти' type='SUBMIT'>
    </div>
    <div class="div_float">
        <input class='form_button' value='Очистить' type='Reset'>
    </div>
</form>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

{{ message }}

{% endblock %}
```

Если смотреть код страницы, то когда слетают стили, появляется ошибка
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/main.css
[HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED 3ms]

Answer (score 0):

В итоге если в **/app/main/**init**.py** добавить в login() получение значения какого-либо поля формы:

```
user_name = request.form.get('user', '')
```

то стили перестают слетать. Я не понимаю как это связано. Кто-нибудь может объяснить?

Comment: Если вы желаете дополнить вопрос, то воспользуйтесь кнопкой править под вопросом. Так как вы дали ответ, то вы не получите никаких объяснений.